# how to get the text from a textArea in gwt?

Tags: gwt, event-handling

I am trying to fetch the text typed in the textArea by the user using a value change handler. Everytime I try to access the text outside the handler I get Null pointer Exception. Why is this happening? How can i get the complete text from the textArea so that I can use it further?

```
display.getmessageTextArea().addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        text=event.getValue();
    }
});

System.out.println(text);
```

when i print the text outside the handler i get null pointer exception. I want ti fetch the text typed in that textArea by the user.

Comment: Please post your code snippet.

Comment: The `System.out.println` is called before the `text` is set at all, which results in a NPE. You can print it in the Handler though.

Comment: I dont to print it anywhere I just want to save the text in some string.If i save the text in the handler and use it outside the handler it doesnt  work.

Comment: You'll have to make sure that you only use `text` after it actually has been set, i.e. after the `ValueChangeHandler` has been fired at least once. A simple `null` check might do it depending on what you want to achieve. Can you not simply add your logic to the Handler? That would be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `textArea.getValue()` method to get the text from a `TextArea` in GWT.

```
display.getmessageTextArea().addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        text=display.getmessageTextArea().getValue();
    }
});

System.out.println(display.getmessageTextArea().getValue());
```

---

`textArea.getValue()` method doesn't return `null` at all. If `TextArea` is empty then it will return you an empty string.

Here is the source code of `TextBoxBase.java` that is super class of `TextArea`

```
  /**
   * Overridden to return "" from an empty text box.
   */
  @Override
  public String getValue() {
    String raw = super.getValue();
    return raw == null ? "" : raw;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final TextArea textArea=new TextArea();
        textArea.setCharacterWidth(22);
        textArea.setVisibleLines(2);
        textArea.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) 
            {
                String addr=textArea.getValue();
                student.setAddress(addr);
                System.out.println(addr);
            }
        });
```